# apply animation to any text in every html element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-animations

I want to apply fade in effect to all text in a web page, but do I have to select every text element like this: h1, p, a, li{ animation: fade-in;} ? What if there is also text just within div "DIV TEXT".
Thanks a lot for your help!

```css
div{
 background: green;
}
@keyframes text-appear {
    from {
          opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
          opacity: 1;
    }
}
h1, text{
  animation: text-appear 2s linear;
}
```

```html
  <div>
    DIV TEXT, no fade in
    <h1>H1</h1>
    <h1>H1</h1>
    <p>P, no fade in</p>
    <a>A, no fade in</a>

    <svg viewBox="0 0 200 38"  >
      <text x="50%" y="50%" fill="red">SVG TEXT</text>
    </svg>
 </div>
```

Comment: Your code looks ok! If you als want to fade in the DIV TEXT then you could wrap it in a `<span>` element so you can target it.

Comment: You can use `class` selector https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.php instead

Answer (score 0):

This selector should work, Selects all elements that are not empty/only whitespace, and that don't have any other children:

```css
div {
  background: green;
}

*:not(:empty):not(:has(*)) {
  animation: text-appear 5s linear;
}

@keyframes text-appear {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  DIV TEXT, no fade in
  <h1>H1</h1>
  <h1>H1</h1>
  <p>P, no fade in</p>
  <a>A, no fade in</a>

  <svg viewBox="0 0 200 38">
      <text x="50%" y="50%" fill="red">SVG TEXT</text>
    </svg>
</div>
```